# Rust copy vector from cycle?

Tags: rust

I can copy a vector from a slice like so:

```
let mut my_vector = Vec::from_iter(other_vector[n..n+5].iter().cloned());
```

Is there a way to copy a vector so that I wrap around the end? e.g., for the vector [1,2,3,4,5] I could copy [5,1,2]

std::iter::Cycle provides a cycle iterator but I'm not sure how to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::iter::Cycle` directly after you converted it to an iterator, and then use `skip` to get to the place you want in the iterator, before using `take` to take the number of elements you want in the new iterator.

```
fn main() {
    let n = 4;
    let other_vector = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let my_vector = Vec::from_iter(other_vector.iter().cycle().skip(n).take(3).cloned());
    dbg!(my_vector);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b35ac31081e6465b478d4cd310c58df3)

Comment: `cloned` (or, in this case, `copied`) is necessary, since otherwise `my_vector` would be a `Vec<&i32>`, not a `Vec<i32>` - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c490c648a78c917e58bd5e6a6314529

Answer (score 0):

With a functional programming approach, you can map through index iterator from 0 to 3 and then collect corresponding vector values (got using modulo concept).

```
fn main(){
let n = 4;
let other_vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let modulo = other_vector.len();
let l = 3;
let my_vector: Vec<i32> = (0..l).into_iter().map(|i| other_vector[(n+i)%modulo]).collect();
dbg!(my_vector);
```

}

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f3e8f8f7e607b770ff363f3f83f7a98)

I do a benchmark to compare the 2 methods std::iter::Cycle (@Prime_Aqasix response) and map/collect method

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use test::Bencher;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn test1(other_vector:&Vec<i32>) {
    let n = 4;
    let my_vector = Vec::from_iter(other_vector.iter().cycle().skip(n).take(3).cloned());
    dbg!(my_vector);
}

fn test2(other_vector:&Vec<i32>) {
    let n = 4;
    let modulo = other_vector.len();
    let l = 3;
    let my_vector: Vec<i32> = (0..l).into_iter().map(|i| other_vector[(n+i)%modulo]).collect();
    dbg!(my_vector);
}

#[bench]
fn bench_test1(bencher: &mut Bencher) {

    let other_vector: Vec<i32> = (0..10000).map(|v| v + 1000).collect();
    bencher.iter(|| test1(&other_vector));
}

#[bench]
fn bench_test2(bencher: &mut Bencher) {

    let other_vector: Vec<i32> = (0..10000).map(|v| v + 1000).collect();
    bencher.iter(|| test2(&other_vector));
}
```

To execute, you just have to run "cargo bench" command. These are my results:

First test:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_test1 ... bench:         686 ns/iter (+/- 487)
test bench_test2 ... bench:         576 ns/iter (+/- 398)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 11.78s
```

Second test:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_test1 ... bench:         696 ns/iter (+/- 755)
test bench_test2 ... bench:         622 ns/iter (+/- 419)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 13.32s
```

Third test:

```
running 2 tests
test bench_test1 ... bench:         638 ns/iter (+/- 537)
test bench_test2 ... bench:         494 ns/iter (+/- 529)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 4.76s
```

Functional programming approach is more likely speedup the copy. This is a good alternative to std::iter::cycle